# find [max,min] value in list of lists python

Tags: python, list, max, min

So I have a list of lists

```
alist = [[distance1,delta-angle1,object1],[distance2,delta-angle2,object2], [distance3,delta-angle3,object3],...]
```

I want to maximize for "distance" and minimize for "delta-angle", which are are the first two elements of each `list` in `alist` and return that particular list.

caveat: `distance` will be a float and `delta-angle` will be in degrees (-180:180)

The goal is to pick the longest distance with the "straightest" angle, but not just the longest or the "straightest" (otherwise known as minimize change in angle)

EDIT: I cannot upload image so here is a link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/apEfd.jpg

I would like to avoid "going back where I was" as in this special case. 
As shown in the second image

IMAGE 2

The third image is the ideal - and since I still haven't thought of a better way to state this: minimize the change in angle from current bearing (which delta-angle is what is stored in `alist` already) and maximize the `distance` or length of available line segments (denoted here by endpoints on boundary in following picture)

IMAGE 3  https://i.stack.imgur.com/apEfd.jpg

Comment: your definition "longest distance with the straightest angle" is quite vague - can you define a utility function? if you have a pair of elements, how can you decide which one is better?

Comment: You can't really get an answer until you actually give a specific formula for choosing which one is better. After you have that you could just used sorted while specifying a key. (more reading: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

Comment: Also, why do you assume you need to "put [the angle] on a scale of [0...360]" to minimize it? Do you really want 89° to be considered more minimal than -45°? If not, leave it as [-180, 180] and just minimize `abs(angle)` instead of `angle`.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: I haven't thought of that - but I guess that could work. Although, I am not sure where to start if I go this direction. To clarify: The longest line is gives the most utility unless the angle(which is the change of direction from some previous bearing) is sharp. So the most utility would come from long lines that fall in a range of -90:0:90 and everything else being of little utility no matter how long the distance is.

Comment: @user1124683: So is the rule "Longest line in [-90, 90], or longest line outside the range if there are no lines within the range"?

Comment: I'd guess `distance*cos(angle)` might be an appropriate metric. That is, "furthest to the right (along the x-axis)".

Comment: @user1124683: That's kind of what I was expecting before the OP's comment, but it doesn't seem to fit what he said in the comment. Maybe if we knew what he actually wanted this for…?

Comment: @abarnert: ok - so yes you are correct I am being ambiguous. Let me see if I can clarify. The distance is the length of a line segment [object] in my alist. The angle is the angle between the common endpoint of the line-segment and a previous location (all on a 2d plane). The rule would be given I traveled from previous location (making that location directly behind me) what is the longest line segment I can take that does not take me back to the previous location.

Comment: @user1124683: That doesn't make much sense. No line segment will take you back to the previous location unless it's the exact opposite of the previous segment. Maybe what you're looking for is the line segment that, when added to the current position (or to the preceding sequence of segments, which is basically the same thing), maximizes the norm? If so, you need to know the current position (or preceding sequence), not just the list of possible moves from this position.

Comment: @user1124683: If you want any further help, you're going to have to explain what your actual use case is, at a higher level. And if you don't know the math well enough to explain it, maybe go to math.stackexchange.com first to figure out your actual problem, then come back here and ask how to implement the solution in Python.

Comment: Ok well stackoverflow will no let me post pictures yet.

Comment: Your pictures still don't explain what the rule is that you want. Why is pt3 better than, say, the lower left corner (which is a bit closer, but has a much smaller angle)? There must be some reason. But if you can't even explain it to us, you can't possibly explain it to the Python interpreter (and, needless to say, neither can we).

Answer (score 1):

Even after clarification, your rule is still ambiguous. You need to figure out what rule you want to implement, before you can code that rule.

If the rule is simple enough, you should be able to write a function that returns a higher value the better the match. In that case, you can just pass that function as the `key` to `max` (or you can `sorted`, or `heapq.nlargest`, etc., depending on what your actual use case is).

For example, if the rule is just "the object with the largest X component is best", as Blckknght says, that's just `distance*cos(angle)`. Except, of course, that you probably want the largest positive or negative X component, so it's actually `abs(that)`. So:

```
def best(alist):
    return max(alist, key=lambda dao: abs(dao[0] * math.cos(dao[1]))
```

(Since each element of the `list` is a `list` of `distance, angle, object`, I've called each of those elements `dao`, so `dao[0]` is the distance, etc.)

What if you can't figure out how to turn the rule into a single key function?

Well, if you can write a comparison function, that compares two `dao` triplets and returns the bigger one, you can use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to turn that into a `key` function. But really, it's not that common that you can write a `cmp` function but can't write a `key` function.

If you need something more complicated, you can always pre-filter the list, or decorate-sort-undecorate, etc.

For example, in a comment, you say:

> the most utility would come from long lines that fall in a range of -90:0:90 and everything else being of little utility no matter how long the distance is.

This is ambiguous, but one way we could interpret it is:

- If there are any objects with an angle in the range [-90, 90], pick the longest out of those objects.
- Otherwise, pick the object with the smallest angle.

I *could* write that as a key function, but let's pretend I didn't know how, and wanted to make everything explicit. It's trivial to write a key function for `longest`—that's just `dao[0]` as the key. And it's also trivial to write a key function for `smallest angle`—that's just `abs(dao[1])`. So:

```
def best(alist):
    acutes = [[d, a, o] for [d, a, o] in alist if abs(a) <= 90]
    if acutes:
        return max(acutes, key=lambda dao: dao[0])
    else:
        return min(alist, key=lambda dao: abs(dao[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = [[0,0,'b'],[-30,50,'a'],
         [45,63,'d'],[100,170,'d'],
         [-2,15,'p']]

def mM(L):
    x,y,_ = zip(*L)
    return (min(x),max(y))

print mM(alist)
```

result

```
(-30, 170)
```

Comment: I don't think the questioner wants separate maximums and minimums, but rather a single combined max/min value.

Comment: That is correct - I want to (maximize,minimize).

Comment: @user1124683 You have an exasparating ununderstandable manner to express. That's a problem